# cordova inappbrowser referencing elements

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

Is  there any way to use cordovas InAppBrowser to reference elements on a page and detect when they are pressed? The page I am referencing has a back button and a close button and I need to know which one is pressed and then close the inAppBrowser.

I am assuming it would look something like this, but I can't seem to make it work

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    ref.executeScript({ 
        code: 
        "document.getElementById('pageHeader').onclick = function() { 
            alert('button was clicked');
        }"
    });
}
```

Is it possible to instead use:

```
executeScript({ link: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" });
```

And then use jQuery?

```
executeScript({ code: "$('#pageHeader').on('click', function() { alert('button was clicked'); }"});
```

Comment: Although the `InAppBrowser` plugin allows you to run script on the displayed page like in your question, that will not work if the page is not yours (i.e. not part of your App) because you will get a permission error. It's ironic, because the most common use of the `InAppBrowser` plugin is to display pages that are not part of the App itself, so the `executeScript` method is pretty much useless.

Comment: @RacilHilan Ahh, do you know if there is a way I can reference when a back button is clicked then? outside of executeScript?

Comment: No, sorry, otherwise I would've posted it in a answer :-). I don't think there is any way to do it. The `executeScript` has an X button to close it, if you don't like it, you can modify how it looks for Android. For iOS it is the standard style and I don't think you can change it, but it looks good.

Comment: @RacilHilan, have you tried executeScript? I've used it and I can execute javascript on external pages. If you tried and didn't work then it might be a bug

Comment: @DanceSC, it should work, but if you use the link approach you should execute the second executeScript on the first executeScript callback to make sure jquery was inserted. And maybe you should execute a first executeScript to check if jquery is already available so you don't inyect it if it's present on the website

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes of course I tried it, otherwise I wouldn't open my mouth :-). I just wanted to test how it works a few months ago so I tried it with very simple JS code and it gave me some permission error. I also tried the CSS injection method and it gave me the same error. Perhaps they've fixed that now, or maybe the page I tried it on was special case. I'm glad to hear that it works, let's see if it will work for the OP. Oh, I only tried it on Android at that time. Is it easy for you to test in on Android and confirm?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow on android and let you know. I suppose that this won't work on websites that use a content security policy meta tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked it on iOS and it's working, you had an error on the syntax

Working example that injects js on bing website `sbBtn` is the search icon button:

```
var ref = window.open("https://www.bing.com/?setlang=es", '_blank');
ref.addEventListener(
    'loadstop',
    function(event) {
        ref.executeScript({
            code: "document.getElementById('sbBtn').onclick = function() {alert('button was clicked');}"
        });
    }
);
```

And the jquery approach:

```
var ref = window.open("https://www.bing.com/?setlang=es", '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    ref.executeScript({
        file: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"
    }, function() {
        ref.executeScript({
            code: "jQuery('#sbBtn').on('click', function() { alert('button was clicked'); });"
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried the top one and I couldn't get it to work, though the problem is I am trying to connect to walgreens using phonegap so I needed a method to detect if their back or cancel buttons have been click. Because of this though I don't know for certain if they are actual buttons or links and if that would effect the javascript .onclick, so I'll test it with the jquery as soon as their servers are back up from maintenance.

Comment: ```http://www.walgreens.com```? I loaded it and it already uses jquery, but I don't see any cancel or back button

Comment: that is because I am using the photo prints api, not their normal website - https://services-qa.walgreens.com/api/util/mweb5url

Comment: so, did you try again? my example works without problems on bing website

Comment: It is not working for me, but I believe it is for reasons outside of the executeScript. I'll mark as answer

Comment: @jcesarmobile, how can i return values on the button click. Alert is working, but return is not working. Can you kindly look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489779/inappbrowser-executescript-return-values-on-button-click-not-working